# kafka consumer polling increase the method execution time

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

in our application,consumer started polling continuously at the load of the application and therefore sometimes it impact the execution time for  one of the 
method by polling in between the method execution.

Method (let say test())which ideally take few millisecond to run in junit case is now taking few seconds for the execution in app.Therfore, would like to skip the polling
 at this point of time,if possible.

In spring integration doc have seen something called PollSkipAdvice/PollSkipStrategy which says The PollSkipAdvice can be used to suppress (skip) a poll.

Could you please suggest,if this can be of any help in above scenario.Would be great, if explain using example.Thanks.

sample config:

```
 <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
    auto-startup="false" channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
        max-messages-per-poll="5" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You scenario isn't clear. Really...

We have here only one adapter with **aggressive** `fixed-delay` every `10` `MILLISECONDS` and only for the small amount of messages.

Consider to increase the poll time and make `max-messages-per-poll` as `-1` to poll all of them for the one poll task.

From other side it isn't clear how that your `test()` method is involved...

Also consider to switch to `<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter>` for better control over messages.

Regarding `PollSkipAdvice`... Really not sure which aim would you like to reach with it...

And one more point. Bear in mind all `<poller>`s use the same `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with the `10` as pool. So, maybe some other long-living task keeps threads from it busy...

This your `<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>` takes only one, but each 10 millis, of course.